# How can I restrict a secret to be accessed only by a certain lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I have the following use case: I have stored a secret on the Secret Store Manager  and I want to make available the value of that secret only for a lambda. The resource based policy of the secret looks like:

```
{
 "Version" : "2012-10-17",
 "Statement" : [ {
   "Effect" : "Deny",
   "NotPrincipal" : {
     "AWS" : "arn:aws:iam::8999990:role/service-role/test-get-secret-role-68hr4lv6"
   },
   "Action" : [
       "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
       "secretsmanager:GetRandomPassword",
       "secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy",
       "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
       "secretsmanager:ListSecrets",
       "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds"
       ],
   "Resource" : "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:99999889:secret:test-test-LLCii9"
 } ]
}
```

But for the lambda is still not allowed to access the secret, seeing as I also added the permissions for SecretManager on the lambda execution role. Is there another approach for this?

Updated:

```
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Effect" : "Deny",
    "NotPrincipal" : {
      "AWS" : [ "arn:aws:iam::254386565891:role/service-role/test-get-secret-role-68hr4lv6", "arn:aws:sts::254386565891:assumed-role/test-get-secret-role-68hr4lv6/test-get-secret", "arn:aws:sts::254386565891:root" ]
    },
    "Action" : [ "secretsmanager:CancelRotateSecret", "secretsmanager:DeleteSecret", "secretsmanager:GetRandomPassword", "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue", "secretsmanager:ListSecrets", "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds", "secretsmanager:PutSecretValue", "secretsmanager:RemoveRegionsFromReplication", "secretsmanager:ReplicateSecretToRegions", "secretsmanager:RestoreSecret", "secretsmanager:RotateSecret", "secretsmanager:StopReplicationToReplica", "secretsmanager:TagResource", "secretsmanager:UntagResource", "secretsmanager:UpdateSecret", "secretsmanager:UpdateSecretVersionStage" ],
    "Resource" : "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:254386565891:secret:test1-LLCii9"
  }, {
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
      "AWS" : [ "arn:aws:iam::254386565891:role/service-role/test-get-secret-role-68hr4lv6"]
    },
    "Action" : "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
    "Resource" : "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:254386565891:secret:test1-LLCii9"
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an explicit `Allow` statement to the resource policy of the secret to allow the Lambda role to access it.

Currently you have omitted your `test-get-secret-role` from the `Deny`-statement, but you also have to specify what should happen (=Allow) when `test-get-secret-role` tries to access the resource. You can read more about combining `Deny` and `Not Principal` [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notprincipal.html).

*Update:*

Another, simpler, way to create a policy that only allows one Lambda GetSecretValue-access to a Secret is the following:

```
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
      "AWS" : [ "/*lambda role Arn*/"]
    },
    "Action" : "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
    "Resource" : "/*secret arn*/"
  }, {
    "Effect" : "Deny",
    "Principal" : "*",
    "Action" : "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
    "Resource" : "/*secret arn*/",
    "Condition": {"ArnNotLike": {"aws:PrincipalArn": "/*lambda role arn*/"}}

  }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this fixed my issue partially.. I updated the policy as you see in the description according to the documentation that you've provided, which specify to add also the assumed role ARN and also the account root. Now I have access to the value, but the problem is if I have a second lambda to which role I will add the policy of SecretManager, it will also be able to access the data and this shouldnt be the case. Do you have any other suggestion on how I can restrict it to only a lambda?

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to add the ```test-get-secret-role``` to the other Lambda as well?

Comment: I have noticed that you have two slightly different Arns for the secret in in your statements (the part after test1-), is this voluntary? You might be referring to two different secrets by accident.

Comment: I mean that I want to restrict the access to this secret to a lambda. No others lambda to be able to access it.

Comment: So even when I add to the role of other lambda , the policy to be able to access secrets. The one above to not be available.

Comment: I couldn't find a problem with your code, I tried it here with two different Lambdas and one lambda gets AccessDenied and the other gets Access. However, AWS recommends using other solutions than ```NotPrincipal```when possible, so I gave you a simpler example in my answer that you can try out as well.

Comment: Thank you! It works :D